# Are Both of these expressions same in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

***Expression 1 -***

```
int a;
int* ap = &a;
```

***Expression 2 -***

```
int a;
int*ap = new a;
```

Comment: No they aren't. What makes you think so?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ In both the cases, `ap` contains the address of `a` right?

Comment: have you checked whether expression 2 compiles?

Comment: No, the 2nd example doesn't even compile.

Comment: In the concept of object Slicing, 

`// rest of code is similar to above 
void somefunc (Base *objp) 
{ 
 objp->display(); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
 Base *bp = new Base(33) ; 
 Derived *dp = new Derived(45, 54); 
 somefunc(bp); 
 somefunc(dp); // No Object Slicing 
 return 0; 
} `

In `somefunc()` we are passing `dp and bp`as arguments, actually these are addresses, that's why I though they both are same??

Could any body explain whats going on here...

Comment: @VijayKumar What does your original question have to do with _object slicing_??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Here only I first encountered `new` keyword for the first time, I thought both are doing the same purposes

Comment: As I said in my 1st comment, they don't. You can read about what the keyword does in the [reference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new). Learning c++ from guessing and trial and error, isn't the right way.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I Thank you very much, I understood the difference between both the experssions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Expression 1 -**

```
int a;
int* ap = &a;
```

**Ans : This is an int pointer which will stay on the stack.**

**Expression 2 -**

```
int a;
int*ap = new a; **// syntax error**
```

**Ans: `new` will allocate memory in heap and this needs manual cleanup (using `delete`), whereas in Expression 1 it will automatically cleanup when it goes out of scope.**

Answer (score 3):

No.

Expression 1 defines a variable `a` of type `int` and a variable `ap` of type `int*`. It also initializes `ap` to the memory address of the previously defined variable `a`.

---

Expression 2 doesn't compile since `new a` isn't valid syntax.

Assuming you meant `new int`, then expression 2 defines a variable `a` of type `int` and a variable `ap` of type `int*`. It also initializes `ap` to point to a dynamically allocated `int`.

---

In expression 1 you have 1 `int` and 1 `int*`.

In expression 2 you have 2 `ints`, one as automatic storage (namely `a`) and one as dynamic storage and 1 `int*` `ap`, `ap` points to the `int` stored through dynamic storage.

Comment: Surely you meant expression 2 in the 2nd paragraph?

Comment: How did you make `int*ap = new a;` compile?

Comment: @Asu yes whoops

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Very good comment, I read right through it, thanks, edited

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ To answer the question, I compiled clang with my custom extension to allow omitting `decltype(a)`.